# Open FTP URL in browser Android

Tags: android, url, browser, ftp

I want to launch an FTP URL in browser. The URL is similar to this:
ftp://192.168.43.1:2121

```
Intent httpIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
String url = "ftp://192.168.43.1:2121";
httpIntent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(httpIntent);
```

This code throws `NoActivityFound` exception. It seems like browsers are unable to recognise it as a URL. But if we explicitly type  `ftp://192.168.43.1:2121` it opens perfectly in browsers.

I found some workaround to explicitly open the `url` in `Chrome` but I want to list all browsers of system in choice.

Comment: How does this relate to programming?

Comment: Without further information, this seems more appropriate on SuperUser.